# Keep getting mongoose.Promise must be a function, got bluebird

Tags: mongoose, bluebird

Can't seem to resolve the following error:

```
mongoose.Promise must be a function, got bluebird
```

Not 100% sure what it's asking so some pointers in the right direction would be great

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your code that is causing this to the question?

Comment: I think the way to go about it is. `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise`

Comment: Thanks @cr05s19xx but that's not working. I think it's to do with Babel (I basically want to use ES6+ in my API). The non-Babel API works fine, but when I integrate it with Babel it throws that error